# ASP.NE WEBSITE takes forever to respond

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

My asp.net web application is encountering down time everyday, it takes forever to respond. But once I stop and start (not iis reset) the website in IIS it will work again. Then hours/a day later it will become unresponsive again. What would be the reason? I'm suspecting an unclosed connection to database but hard to find them. The codes were made by the previous programmer.

Comment: If you can't see the problem browsing the code and with full access to the server then hardly you will get a good answer here (but people may still try to guess for you, indeed). Logs, system events and Performance Counters are usually very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the queue length which is a setting under apppool.
2. If its happening during a particular time of the day then please check the resource utilization like CPU/RAM consumed during that particular time.

There are APM tools like App Insight available which you can use to monitor the request response time for the requests.

You can implement Google analytics to see number of users online or requesting to see if its threshold issue.

Comment: I'll do your recommendations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Look into IIS logs during the time of issue and check the time-taken field. If its above normal, proceed to the following step
2. During the time of issue (before you restart the website), capture a manual hang dump of the w3wp process - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugdiag/2013/03/15/debug-diagnostic-1-2-generate-a-manual-hang-dump-on-a-specific-process/
3. Run Debug Diag report and share it if you can. It'll tell you things that are possible going wrong.